# How to install from .tar.tar files?

Tags: drivers, software-installation, archive

I have a problem trying to install some drivers for my printer. I have a .tar archive with some .tar.tar archives and .deb archives. I wonder how can I install them.

Uncle Google told me only about installing from .tar.gz or .tar.bz2 files. And the official site didn't have any manuals for installing the drivers.

Comment: Depends on the contents of the archives. Some archives are scripts, others source code, and others binaries.

Comment: As I said the only files I have in the main archive are some .tar.tar and .deb files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easiest to use one of the .deb packages.

The packages should be labelled with the architecture they were compiled for. Now you need to choose the correct one.

If you have a 64bit system, look for one with `amd64`, `x86_64`, `x86-64` or just `64bit` in the name.

If you're running a 32bit system, search for something like `i386`, `x86` or `32bit`.

When you've found the correct package, extract it from the tar archive and open a terminal in the extraction directory. Install the package using

```
sudo dpkg -i name_of_the_package.deb
```

If dpkg returns some dependency errors, fix them by running `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: What does `sudo apt-get install -f` exactly do?

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/apt-get.8.html